# After upgrade debian 9 (stretch) to debian 10 (buster) command 'apt upgrade' fail because a driver

Tags: debian, debian-stretch

I can not install or remove any package using apt. Gnome desktop environment does not work either.

```
root@debian:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

...

```
root@debian:~# uname -a
Linux debian 4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1 (2019-04-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

...

```
root@debian:~# apt update
Hit:1 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
369 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

...

```
root@debian:~# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 va-driver-all : Depends: mesa-va-drivers but it is not installed
 va-driver-all:i386 : Depends: mesa-va-drivers:i386 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

...

```
root@debian:~# apt install mesa-va-drivers
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 va-driver-all:i386 : Depends: mesa-va-drivers:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

...

```
root@debian:~# apt install mesa-va-drivers:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 va-driver-all : Depends: mesa-va-drivers but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

...

```
root@debian:~# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  alsa-base bridge-utils cpufrequtils dmz-cursor-theme docbook-xml ebtables freerdp-x11 gcj-6-jre-lib gir1.2-mate-panel gir1.2-matepanelapplet-4.0
  gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-themes-standard gnupg-agent guile-2.0-libs libapparmor-perl libattr1:i386 libbabeltrace-ctf1 libbind9-140 libblas-common
  libboost-chrono1.62.0 libboost-python1.62.0 libboost-random1.62.0 libboost-regex1.67.0 libboost-thread1.62.0 libclang1-3.9 libcomerr2:i386
  libdns-export162 libdns162 libegl-mesa0:i386 libegl1:i386 libetpan17 libfile-copy-recursive-perl libfreerdp-cache1.1 libfreerdp-client1.1
  libfreerdp-codec1.1 libfreerdp-common1.1.0 libfreerdp-core1.1 libfreerdp-crypto1.1 libfreerdp-gdi1.1 libfreerdp-locale1.1 libfreerdp-plugins-standard
  libfreerdp-primitives1.1 libfreerdp-rail1.1 libfreerdp-utils1.1 libgbm1:i386 libgcab-1.0-0 libgcj-common libgcj17 libgcr-3-common libgfortran3
  libgmime-2.6-0 libgnome-autoar-common libgnome-games-support-1-2 libgom-1.0-common libgutenprint2 libhttp-parser2.1 libicu57:i386 libidn11:i386
  libisc-export160 libisc160 libisccc140 libisccfg140 libjim0.76 libllvm4.0 liblouis12 liblouisutdml7 liblvm2app2.2 liblvm2cmd2.02 liblwres141
  libmono-data-tds4.0-cil libnotmuch4 libntfs-3g871 libonig4 libpisock9 libprocps6 librados2 librarian0 librbd1 libsmpeg0 libsndio6.1:i386 libsodium18
  libstd-rust-1.24 libstdc++-4.9-dev libsuitesparseconfig4 libtinfo-dev libtomcrypt0 libtommath1 libunbound2 libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386
  libwayland-server0:i386 libwinpr-crt0.1 libwinpr-crypto0.1 libwinpr-dsparse0.1 libwinpr-environment0.1 libwinpr-error0.1 libwinpr-file0.1
  libwinpr-handle0.1 libwinpr-heap0.1 libwinpr-input0.1 libwinpr-interlocked0.1 libwinpr-library0.1 libwinpr-path0.1 libwinpr-pool0.1 libwinpr-registry0.1
  libwinpr-rpc0.1 libwinpr-sspi0.1 libwinpr-synch0.1 libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 libwinpr-thread0.1 libwinpr-utils0.1 libxen-4.8 libxfont1 libxfreerdp-client1.1
  linux-headers-4.9.0-8-amd64 linux-headers-4.9.0-8-common linux-image-4.9.0-8-amd64 openbios-ppc openbios-sparc openhackware python-certifi python-imaging
  python-pam python-requests python-twisted-web python-urllib3 python-zeitgeist python3-pyasn1 qemu-slof qemu-system qemu-system-mips qemu-system-misc
  qemu-system-ppc qemu-system-sparc qemu-user qemu-user-binfmt rarian-compat sgml-data snap-confine tcpd ubuntu-core-launcher xml-core
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mesa-va-drivers mesa-va-drivers:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mesa-va-drivers mesa-va-drivers:i386
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 369 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4,105 kB of archives.
After this operation, 38.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 415628 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mesa-va-drivers_18.3.6-2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-va-drivers:i386 (18.3.6-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mesa-va-drivers_18.3.6-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_drv_video.so', which is also in package vdpau-va-driver:i386 0.7.4-dmo5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mesa-va-drivers_18.3.6-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (18.3.6-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mesa-va-drivers_18.3.6-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_drv_video.so', which is also in package vdpau-va-driver:amd64 0.7.4-dmo5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mesa-va-drivers_18.3.6-2_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mesa-va-drivers_18.3.6-2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

...

```
root@debian:~# apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 va-driver-all : Depends: mesa-va-drivers but it is not installed
 va-driver-all:i386 : Depends: mesa-va-drivers:i386 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

...

```
apt-get remove ".*:i386"
...
...
...
Package 'zangband:i386' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'bro:i386' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dosbox:i386' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dosbox-debug:i386' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libzmq3-dev:i386' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libzmq5:i386' is not installed, so not removed. Did you mean 'libzmq5'?
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 va-driver-all : Depends: mesa-va-drivers but it is not going to be installed
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 4.0.1~stretch)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

...

```
root@debian:~# apt purge va-driver-all
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 va-driver-all:i386 : Depends: mesa-va-drivers:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

...

```
root@debian:~# apt purge va-driver-all:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 va-driver-all : Depends: mesa-va-drivers but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Do you actually need that package?  Try uninstalling it.  Do you actually need the i386 support?  Try removing that?

Comment: I do not need that specific package, but I think it is related to a graphic driver and I need a graphic desktop environment.

Comment: I have tried to uninstall using apt and get the same error.

Comment: List all the packages at the same time in your remove `apt-get remove mesa-va-drivers va-driver-all va-driver-all:i386`.  In any cause, if that doesn't work, just restore your backup before you upgraded, or re-install.

Comment: After running the full command (apt-get remove mesa-va-drivers va-driver-all va-driver-all: i386) it worked. Packages va-driver-all: amd64 and va-driver-all: i386 were removed. Thanks.

Comment: I am currently running full upgrade, everything seems to be fine. Thank you @Zoredache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Zoredache, the following works for me:

```
root@debian:~# apt-get remove mesa-va-drivers va-driver-all va-driver-all:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mesa-va-drivers' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  alsa-base bridge-utils cpufrequtils dmz-cursor-theme docbook-xml ebtables freerdp-x11 gcj-6-jre-lib gir1.2-mate-panel gir1.2-matepanelapplet-4.0
  gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-themes-standard gnupg-agent guile-2.0-libs libapparmor-perl libattr1:i386 libbabeltrace-ctf1 libbind9-140 libblas-common
  libboost-chrono1.62.0 libboost-python1.62.0 libboost-random1.62.0 libboost-regex1.67.0 libboost-thread1.62.0 libclang1-3.9 libcomerr2:i386
  libdns-export162 libdns162 libegl-mesa0:i386 libegl1:i386 libetpan17 libfile-copy-recursive-perl libfreerdp-cache1.1 libfreerdp-client1.1
  libfreerdp-codec1.1 libfreerdp-common1.1.0 libfreerdp-core1.1 libfreerdp-crypto1.1 libfreerdp-gdi1.1 libfreerdp-locale1.1 libfreerdp-plugins-standard
  libfreerdp-primitives1.1 libfreerdp-rail1.1 libfreerdp-utils1.1 libgbm1:i386 libgcab-1.0-0 libgcj-common libgcj17 libgcr-3-common libgfortran3
  libgmime-2.6-0 libgnome-autoar-common libgnome-games-support-1-2 libgom-1.0-common libgutenprint2 libhttp-parser2.1 libicu57:i386 libidn11:i386
  libisc-export160 libisc160 libisccc140 libisccfg140 libjim0.76 libllvm4.0 liblouis12 liblouisutdml7 liblvm2app2.2 liblvm2cmd2.02 liblwres141
  libmono-data-tds4.0-cil libnotmuch4 libntfs-3g871 libonig4 libpisock9 libprocps6 librados2 librarian0 librbd1 libsmpeg0 libsndio6.1:i386 libsodium18
  libstd-rust-1.24 libstdc++-4.9-dev libsuitesparseconfig4 libtinfo-dev libtomcrypt0 libtommath1 libunbound2 libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386
  libwayland-server0:i386 libwinpr-crt0.1 libwinpr-crypto0.1 libwinpr-dsparse0.1 libwinpr-environment0.1 libwinpr-error0.1 libwinpr-file0.1
  libwinpr-handle0.1 libwinpr-heap0.1 libwinpr-input0.1 libwinpr-interlocked0.1 libwinpr-library0.1 libwinpr-path0.1 libwinpr-pool0.1 libwinpr-registry0.1
  libwinpr-rpc0.1 libwinpr-sspi0.1 libwinpr-synch0.1 libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 libwinpr-thread0.1 libwinpr-utils0.1 libxen-4.8 libxfont1 libxfreerdp-client1.1
  linux-headers-4.9.0-8-amd64 linux-headers-4.9.0-8-common linux-image-4.9.0-8-amd64 openbios-ppc openbios-sparc openhackware python-certifi python-imaging
  python-pam python-requests python-twisted-web python-urllib3 python-zeitgeist python3-pyasn1 qemu-slof qemu-system qemu-system-mips qemu-system-misc
  qemu-system-ppc qemu-system-sparc qemu-user qemu-user-binfmt rarian-compat sgml-data snap-confine tcpd ubuntu-core-launcher xml-core
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  va-driver-all va-driver-all:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 369 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 45.1 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 415627 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing va-driver-all:amd64 (2.4.0-1) ...
Removing va-driver-all:i386 (2.4.0-1) ...
```